# in R: how to take value from Nth cell and subtract from every cell in Nth column

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data set that looks as follows:

```
subvalues <- c(1:10)

df <- data.frame(x = rpois(40,2), y = rpois(40,2), z = rpois(40,2), q = rpois(40,2), t = rpois(40,2))
```

I want to take the value from the first cell of `subvalues` and subtract that from every cell in x, then the 2nd cell of `subvalues` and subtract it from every cell in z, and so on - Thereby generating a new `dataframe` where every row in x, z etc. are new values (original value minus value from selected cell of `subvalues`)

note that my actual data set is thousands of rows and columns, so brute-forcing it is not an option.

What i am looking for is

1: A function/loop for picking out first the first cell of subvalues (for further use), then on the 2nd loop picking out the 2nd cell, etc.

2: How to apply the value from the selected cell from subvalues on every cell in a given column (subtract first row of subvalue from every row in column x, then subtract 2nd row of subvalues from every row in column z, etc)

From what I have gathered I need to use the mutate_at function but I have no idea how to create a function that selects first the first row of subvalues, then the 2nd, etc.

The desired output would be 5 columns with every row a new value (product of original values in the rows minus the particular subvalue selected for that column) - new columns = x2, y2, z2, q2, t2:

Q2    Y2    z2    q2....etc

xa-1 ya-2 za-3  qa-4
xb-1  yb-2 zb-3  qb-4
xc-1  yc-2 zc-3  qc-4
xe-1  yd-2 zd-3  qd-4
xf-1  ye-2 ze-3  qe-4
xg-1  yf-2 zf-3  qf-4
xh-1  yg-2 zg-3  qg-4

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It could be done with `outer`

```
outer(df$x, subvalues, `-`)
outer(df$z, subvalues, `-`)
```

In a loop, it would be

```
lapply(df[c('x', 'z')], outer, subvalues, `-`)
```

---

If we want to do this in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(x, z), list(newcol =  ~map(., ~ .x - subvalues))) %>%
    unnest(ends_with('newcol')) %>% 
    cbind(subvalues)
```

---

Or with `crossing`

```
imap(df %>%
       select(x, z), ~ crossing(!! .y := .x, subvalues) %>% 
                          mutate(!! str_c('diff', .y) := reduce(., `-`))) %>% 
   bind_cols
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this helps but doesn't quite solve the problem - these solutions use <every> cell from subvalues on every column - what I am trying to do is to select specifically only 1 cell from subvalues (say first cell) and use that for subtraction on every row in x, then select specifically cell 2 from subvalues and use that for subtraction on every row of y. - this should result in a new column (x2) with as many rows as x (no more no less)

Also I am need to select 'every nth' column (every 2nd), because of the size of my actual dataset does not allow me to select manually

Comment: @Icewaffle  Please update your post with the expected output from the input example. Also, use a `seed` for reproducibility

Comment: I have added the expected output. Sorry for the mess, I did not figure out how to make indents (4 spaces did not work), i hope it is decipherable

Comment: The outer also gives a matrix output i.e. `outer(df$x, subvalues, `-`)[, c(FALSE, TRUE)]`  selects every 2nd column

Comment: The problem with the outer function is 1: Because of the size of the data (thousands of columns) it is not viable for me to call the columns manually (df$x, df$y is no-go, I need a function/loop that will systematically and automatically go through the columns in an ordered way ala df$i+1 or something)
2: It still takes every cell from subvalues and use on every column - what I need is for it to <only> take the first cell from subvalues when producing the new column for x (x2), to <only> use the 2nd cell from subvalues when producing the new column for y (y2), etc.